# Django rest framework How to fix many-to-many n+1 error?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(choices=CLASS_NUMBERS,
                              max_length=2,
                              verbose_name="Номер класса")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                            verbose_name="Название класса")
    group_teacher = models.ForeignKey('users.Teacher',
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                      verbose_name="Классный руководитель",
                                      related_name='group_teacher')
    students = models.ManyToManyField('users.Student',
                                      verbose_name="Ученики", blank=True,
                                      related_name='group_students')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                verbose_name="Преподаватель", related_name='teacher_user')
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                verbose_name="Ученик", related_name='student_user')
```

and serializers:

```
class TeacherSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = [
            'user'
        ]

class StudentsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = [
            'user'
        ]

class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = [
            'id',
            'number',
            'name',
            'code',
            'group_teacher',
            'students',
        ]
```

When I make an appeal to the api I get warnings:

> Potential n+1 query detected on `Teacher.user` Potential n+1 query
> detected on `Teacher.user` Potential n+1 query detected on
> `Student.user` Potential n+1 query detected on `Student.user`
> Potential n+1 query detected on `Student.user` Potential n+1 query
> detected on `Student.user`

[Queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYaHb.png)

my view set:

```
class GroupModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Group.objects.all().prefetch_related('students')
```

How to fix these errors n+1, select_related does not let me select the model of students and teachers

Comment: Where do you use `TeacherSerializer` and `StudentsSerializer`?

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how to detect N + 1 warnings?

Answer (score 1):

The N+1 query problem happens when the data access framework executed N additional SQL statements to fetch the same data that could have been retrieved when executing the primary SQL query.

You are trying to reach the same database table from all serializers

in your case, this will work

```
class TeacherSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = "__all__"

class StudentsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = "__all__"

class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = [
            'id',
            'number',
            'name',
            'code',
            'group_teacher',
            'students',
        ]
```

---

```
class GroupModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Group.objects.all().prefetch_related('group_teacher', 'group_students')
```

Using the related_name allows you to specify a simpler or more legible name to get the reverse relation. In this case, if you specify `user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tech_user')`, the call would then be `User.tech_user.all()`

```
prefetch_related('tech_user')
```

Comment: Note that prefetch_related does make M queries, M being the number of related objects, I just mention this because people tends to think that it does a SQL join (myself included), which is not: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related
This will be done Python side by Django and then cached

Comment: Cannot find 'group_students' on Group object, 'group_students' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()